# refer-clojure for boot repl

Tags: clojure, namespaces, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to set up [boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) to let me use [better-cond](https://github.com/Engelberg/better-cond) in the REPL. I've put this into my build.boot:

```
(refer-clojure :exclude '[rand rand-int struct cond])
(require '[better-cond.core :refer [cond]])
```

However, when I start `boot repl`, I get this warning:

```
WARNING: cond already refers to: #'clojure.core/cond in namespace: boot.user,
being replaced by: #'better-cond.core/cond
```

`cond` does invoke better-cond, but how do I get rid of the warning?

I don't want to get into the habit of ignoring compiler warnings.

Comment: Since it's usually easier to [reload](https://github.com/samestep/boot-refresh) another source file than to reload `build.boot`, I would instead run your REPL in a namespace other than `boot.user`, allowing you to use `(ns (:refer-clojure ,,,))`.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to turn off this warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you would prefer to work in `boot.user`, you can use [`ns-unmap`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns-unmap) instead of `refer-clojure`:

```
$ boot -d better-cond:1.0.1 repl
boot.user=> (run! #(ns-unmap *ns* %) '[rand rand-int struct cond])
boot.user=> (require '[better-cond.core :refer [cond]])
```